# AWS ELB health check fails on LDAP authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, amazon-elb, healthcheck

I am running a Docker container through ECS. The container runs an Apache server hosting a simple web application. However, the server requires LDAP authentication to access the page.

I am using a Service configured with an ELB to manage the distribution across ECS. I am running into a problem where the health check is failing for all instances. From local testing I know that the Docker container/server works.

[AWS ELB Health Check docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-healthchecks.html#health-check-configuration) state that a `200 OK` response is required to pass the health check (my ping path is `/index.html`). However, LDAP authentication failure will return `401 Authorization Required`.

How to I get the health check to pass without disabling LDAP?

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689333/how-to-instruct-an-aws-elb-to-consider-a-health-check-that-returns-a-403-code-as) suggests just switching the health check to a TCP health check, though that doesn't *feel* right. Happy to do it if it's the correct way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an 'unprotected' page? Like a login page?

If so, then you could use this page as the ELB health check.

If not, can you add a simple page (ping.html) which does not require LDAP authentication?

Comment: That's a good idea, I can add such a page. I'll keep the question open for a little bit since I am curious to know if there is a way without doing that.

Comment: And apparently [I should have looked harder on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921370/aws-load-balancer-with-no-health-check-or-make-it-work-with-non-200-response) before asking :)